# How to get current user id from wordpress user table while logging in

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to store user data into a custom table while logging in, so I have to fetch user id from user table of wordpress

I have tried `get_current_user_id();` but it always returns `0`

Comment: Details matter.  _WHERE_ do you have this code? It must be called _after_ the WP install has lifted, so normally this would be called within a hook for example.  A `0` response means that WP does not recognize any user being logged in - so either the user is not logged in, OR you're calling this in a place / way that WP hasn't had a chance to recognize that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

write it in your html and you will get your current user ID

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
//if you want another thing like his name or any things
print_r($current_user);
//if you want ID
?>
<h1><?php echo $current_user->ID;?></h1>
```

Comment: @cale_b WP themes contain HTML correct. if you put wp_get_current_user(); with HTML it will work?

Comment: @ShivendraSingh - technically, it will work.  But that is _not_ the right place to put it typically...

Comment: @ShivendraSingh - Yes.  It just needs to be wrapped within PHP tags.  There are examples [on this page](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/#HTML_in_PHP) - **IMPORTANT**: NEVER use "Short tags" ( a short tag is `<?`).  Always use full tags: `<?php`

Comment: i will update the answer to make famllier with HTML

Comment: but the need of wp_get_current_user() is within the custom function